# How to find rasterised elements in a vector converted from Illustrator16 to EPS 10

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, raster

In a way to meet the Shutterstock guidelines I need to convert my Illustrator ai vector files to EPS 10 format. This conversion can create rasterised elements in an EPS10 files. Shutterstock does not accept vector files which contain raster elements, so the question is -

How can I know if the converted file has any raster elements and how can I treat the issue if there are raster elements.

I use gradient tool in a source ai file.

Comment: Close, then reopen the EPS after you've saved it.

Comment: and how can I understand there are rasters in a very complex work?

Comment: I don't understand that comment.

Comment: If I reopen EPS file let say with 100 layers and multiple elements - how can I know that some of them were rasterised instead of being vectors as needed?

Comment: Select > Object > RGB Images or Select > Object > CMYK Images

Comment: sad to say, i cannot find these submenus inCS6. Sorry for this unclear issue

Comment: I have the same problem with Shutterstock. Here are some of their guideliness to avoid the problem. https://www.shutterstock.com/blog/bitmapping-101-troubleshooting-eps-files-in-illustrator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, all raster elements should be listed in the **Links** panel:

[image]

You can show this enabling it in the Window menu

Comment: Good catch.. yup

Comment: From that same pallet, shift-select all of the links, then click the "Go To Link" button (looks like an arrow pointing to a document icon). That will select all of the raster items and you can ditch 'em with a press of the delete key. May not be the best thing for your artwork, but it will make sure there are no raster items in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Expand all the objects with effects first.
Gradients, transforms, blends, etc.